# Prove that equality is symmetric in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I want to prove that `=` is *symmetric* in lambda calculus. ie. If $E=E'$ then $E'=E$.

From text I came across that if for instance

$$
E_1 \to_\beta E_2 \to_\beta E_3
$$

and $E \equiv E_1$ and $E' \equiv E_3$ then $E=E'$.

From this to prove that $E'=E$ so to prove that they are symmetric, I think somehow I need to show that

$$
E_3 \to E_2 \to E_1
$$

via either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ or $\eta$ conversion.

How can I prove that $E'=E$ so to prove that `=` is symmetric?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Usually the fact that $=$ is symmetric is already stated in the definition of $=$. Which definition of $=$ are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first try at this.

If $E=E'$ then by Leibnitz's law

$$
\lambda V.E = \lambda V.E'
$$

If we apply $E^*$ to both since they are the same function

$$
EE^* = E'E^*
$$

and

$$
E'E^* = EE^*
$$

Hence, if $E=E'$ then $E'=E$.

$\square$